# How to add/remove many-to-many relation with entity framework by entity key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, entity-relationship, objectcontext

I tried:

```
using (Entities e = new Entities())
{
    EntityKey key = new EntityKey("Entities.Users", "UserId", 20);
    User user = new User { EntityKey = key};
    Role role = e.Roles.FirstOrDefault();
    //role.Users.Attach(user); //throws (when uncommented...) InvalidOperationException:
    //The object being attached to the source object is not attached to the same ObjectContext as the source object.
    role.Users.Add(user); //throws InvalidOperationException too:
    //The object cannot be added to the ObjectStateManager because it already has an EntityKey. Use ObjectContext.Attach to attach an object that has an existing key.
    e.SaveChanges();
}
```

When trying to use Remove() without calling attach before no exception is thrown but relation not deleted.

Comment: Is "Entities" in your example of type System.Data.Entity.DbContext?

Comment: Post research: If "AttachTo" is being used then "Entities" must be an ObjectContext.

Comment: LOL probably, that's an old post... added tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
User user = new User {UserId = 20};
e.AttachTo("Users", user);
Role role = e.Roles.FirstOrDefault();
role.Users.Add(user);
e.SaveChanges();
```

I find it much easier to work with Stub Entities (like the above user) rather than EntityKeys.

See this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/06/19/tip-26-how-to-avoid-database-queries-using-stub-entities.aspx) for more info on Stub Entity techniques.

Hope this helps

Alex