# populating navigation collection using IDs without a reference to the associated entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two entities

```
    public class Business
{
    public int BusinessId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Category> Categories = {get;set;}
}
```

And

```
    public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I get from my clients a Json containing one business ID and collection of its categories IDs (there is a constant number of categories and every businesses registers a few, ex. "private teacher - highschool" "private teacher - elementary" etc).

I want to be able to create the businesses and associate them without loading the relevant categories entites first.

I know it is possible using foreignKey attribute in one-on-one navigation property:

```
//EXAMPLE OF 1-1
 public class Business
{
    [ForeignKey]
    public int CatId{ get; set; }
    public Category cat {get;set;}
}
```

But couldn't find solution for Collection Navigation properties.

Performance-wise it is a disaster,
In a test I wrote creating 100 Businesses with 3 categories out of a 1000 categories took over 5 Sec!

```
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            using (Model m = new Model())
            {
            Business biz = new Business();
            biz.Categories.Add(m.Categories.Find(3));
            biz.Categories.Add(m.Categories.Find(5));
            biz.Categories.Add(m.Categories.Find(63));

            }
        }
        DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine(end - start);
```

(using the same DbContext is both wrong and only gets me to 3 seconds).

I know I can use a workaround and store all my categories in a static dictionary and fetch from there but 
A. I'm not sure EF would not create new instances for them every time
B. Even if I overcome A, I still want an EF solution to this matter, it made me think maybe i shouldn't use EF at all and stick to the old T-SQL and Stored Procedures.
Maybe EF cannot compete with a specifically designed T-SQL by any means (not 60% less but 600%).
All that Lambadas, predicates and LINQ ain't that much of a simplification of development comparing to T-SQL.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to the relationship between `Business` and `Category`. Is that supposed to be a many-to-many, or a one-to-many ? Because from the example you gave it looks like you have it as a one-to-many.

Comment: Actually it can be either, performance was terrible for both cases (checked it today) is it possible that something is wrong with my connection or settings? Because i cant believe this is how EF reacts. Is it the same on other machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for are Stub Entities.  Essentially you create an object locally with just the primary key filled in and use that in place of fetching the whole thing from the database.   See this [blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/19/tip-26-how-to-avoid-database-queries-using-stub-entities.aspx) although it's a bit old.  Also this similar [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1085126/1539015).

Essentially you would have code like the below (but this was an older EF version..see below)

```
Category stub = new Category() {CategoryId = 3};
ctx.AttachTo("Categories", stub);

biz.Categories.Add(stub);
```

The AttachTo is putting the entity in the context as Unchanged, not Added.

But in this case ctx is an ObjectContext.  Since you're using EF6 you will most likely want to use the DbSet.Attach method, so you would probably have something more like

```
context.Categories.Attach(stub);
```

Honestly though I don't think I've done this in EF6 so I'm not positive this is right...but still the concept is a Stub Entity so that's what you'd want to do your searches with.  Good luck!

Comment: Sounds great! I'll test it tomorrow before i sign as answer. I searched the net for hours and haven't heard of this smart technique.